# How to skip rows of a DataFrame during application of a function in case of error?

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have a function that applies some codes (cleaning and detection) to a DataFrame. I want to just skip those rows that cause an error during the application of the function. How can I do so?

The code:

```
def myfunction(text):

 return ....


df['new columns']=df.apply(myfunction)
```

Comment: Probably easiest to just handle exceptions in the function definition  - you could have the function return "error" for those rows, and then just filter them out of the df.

Comment: Thanks Toby. I'll try. meanwhile, could you link an example on how to do this?